# Google Maps Application Not Rendering in Android Studio

Tags: android

I'm new to android, I want to make an application with Google maps integrated on it, and even the demo project in Android Studio shows a rendering error posted below:

http://imgur.com/JVI3b3t

I don't know what to do here, I've made other activities in classes and this fragment is not working.

Comment: Because it works at runtime.

Comment: It doesn't, it is showing an error when I try to run the activity:



public void mapLaunch(View view) {
        Intent launchMapActivity = new Intent(FindSlots.this,MapScreen.class);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        startActivity(launchMapActivity);
    }



This is how I'm launching this file, any errors?

Comment: Why setContentView stays between intent definition and startActivity ? And the posted thing you seeing is not related why you not seeing map. So its just design-time related warning.